# DB query: How to count maximum for several columns

Tags: sql

Assume I have the following table

```
claim_date   person_type
------------------------
01-01-2012         adult
05-05-2012         adult
12-12-2012         adult
12-12-2012         adult
05-05-2012         child
05-05-2012         child
12-12-2012         child
```

When I execute the following query:

```
select 
    claim_date, 
    sum(case when person_type = 'adult' then 1 else 0 end) as "nbr_of_adults",
    sum(case when person_type = 'child' then 1 else 0 end) as "nbr_of_children"
  from my_table
group by claim_date
;
```

I get this result here:

```
claim_date   nbr_of_adults    nbr_of_children
---------------------------------------------
01-01-2012               1                  0
05-05-2012               1                  2
12-12-2012               2                  1
```

What I would like to receive is the maximum number of adults (here: 2) and the maximum number of children (here: 2).
Is there a way to achieve this with a single query? Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use derived table to get counts, and then select max:

```
select max(nbr_of_adults) max_adults,
       max(nbr_of_children) max_children
from
(
  select 
      sum(case when person_type = 'adult' then 1 else 0 end) as "nbr_of_adults",
      sum(case when person_type = 'child' then 1 else 0 end) as "nbr_of_children"
    from my_table
  group by claim_date
) a
```

Answer (score 2):

With nested query :

```
    select max(nbr_of_adults) maxAd, max(nbr_of_children), maxCh from
    (
        select 
          claim_date, 
          sum(case when person_type = 'adult' then 1 else 0 end) as "nbr_of_adults",
          sum(case when person_type = 'child' then 1 else 0 end) as "nbr_of_children"
          from my_table
          group by claim_date    
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is your dbms, but on sybase it works:

```
select     
    max(sum(case when person_type = 'adult' then 1 else 0 end)) as "nbr_of_adults",
    max(sum(case when person_type = 'child' then 1 else 0 end)) as "nbr_of_children"
  from my_table
group by claim_date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select     
person_type,     
sum(case when person_type = 'adult' then 1 else 0 end) as "nbr_of_adults",     
sum(case when person_type = 'child' then 1 else 0 end) as "nbr_of_children"   
from my_table 
group by claim_date ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL product supports window aggregate functions, you could try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  MAX(COUNT(CASE person_type WHEN 'adult' THEN 1 END)) OVER () AS max_adult_count,
  MAX(COUNT(CASE person_type WHEN 'child' THEN 1 END)) OVER () AS max_child_count
FROM claim_table
GROUP BY claim_date
```

I also replaced your conditional SUM with a conditional COUNT, which seemed to me both clearer and more succinct.