# SQL Query with MAX and CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL query and its output is as shown below:

```
select stds.classID as classID, stds.clsLimit as clsLimit
  , max(stds.id)as maxStdsID  
from class cls 
left outer join students stds
on cls.id = stds.classID
group by stds.classID,stds.clsLimit
```

[image]

For each classID, I want to pick the max of maxStdsID which has clsLimit as 1. 
If there is no maxStdsID that has clsLimit as 1, then I would want to pick the max of maxStdsID which has clsLimit as 0

I tried the same with the below logic

```
select stds.classID as classID
  , max(CASE WHEN stds.clsLimit = 1 then stds.id else stds.id end) as maxStdsID  
from class cls 
left outer join students stds
on cls.id = stds.classID
group by stds.classID
```

I am not getting the desired output.

Comment: Check this for More Details : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138869/db-query-how-to-count-maximum-for-several-columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close . . . but use `coalesce()`:

```
select cls.classID,
       coalesce(max(case when stds.clsLimit = 1 then stds.id end),
                max(case when stds.clslimit = 0 then stds.id end)
               ) as maxStdsID  
from class cls left outer join
     students stds
     on cls.id = stds.classID
group by cls.classID;
```

If there is no value for "1", then this picks up the maximum value for "0".

Note that I changed the aggregation column to use the column from the *first* table in the `left join`, rather than the second table.

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
select stds.classID as classID ,  stds.clsLimit as clsLimit , 
max(stds.id)as maxStdsID  
from class cls 
left outer join students stds
on cls.id = stds.classID
where stds.clsLimt = CASE WHEN stds.clsLimit = 1 then 1 ELSE 0 END
group by stds.classID,stds.clsLimit
```